# Multiple logic apps sharing the same parameters file

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, sqlconnection, azure-rm-template

We have many logic apps. 
As there are so many logic apps, its not practical to keep them all in a single arm template as it becomes unwieldy so each logic app is in its own arm template.

All the logic apps have connection to the same sql server, so it makes sense to use a single parameters file for all the logic apps.

The issue comes when we remove the individual sql connection from each logic app, and reference the single connection in the params file. each time the logic app is re-opened in the visual studio designer, the sql connection is re-added by visual studio, as if each logic app arm template needs its own sql connection.

is it possible to develop logic apps in visual studio and have them all share the same sql connection?

Comment: Hi, is this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62350536/azure-file-system-connector/62380743#62380743) helpful to your problem ?

Comment: Hi. Its related but doesnt help unfortunately. it advocates doing all changes in the azure browser based UI, which is fine if dealing with one or two logic apps, but when dealing with 20+ & trying to use devops for deployment, the idea is a non starter.