# Parameters are linked of two different Azure logic app Standard

Tags: azure, azure-logic-app-standard

I have two different Azure Logic Standard App. One Logic App standard was created manually and with multiple workflows. The second Logic app gets created via pipeline. The issue that I am facing is with Parameters. When I change the parameters of one logic app, another logic app's parameters somehow get changed as well. Can someone point me toward a possible reason for such an issue?

Comment: Have you created both the logic app in the same resource group and same location?

Comment: Yes, and storage account is also same.

Comment: If you will create the logic apps in same resource group and location then AFAIK, the connections and the parameters you create will be linked. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62350536/azure-file-system-connector/62380743#62380743

Comment: Can you please share the workflow of both the logic apps?

Comment: Is the same app service plan running the two logic apps?

Answer (score 0):

> When I change the parameters of one logic app, another logic app's parameters somehow get changed as well. Can someone point me toward a possible reason for such an issue?

AFAIK, this might happen if both of your logic apps created in the same resource group and same location.

When you will create a connection in one logic app, you can also see the same connection in the other logic app if both shares the same resource group.

**First Logic app**-

[image]

**Second Logic app**-

[image]

You can check with the product team if you would like to get more information on it.

***References***-

[Azure file system connector - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62350536/azure-file-system-connector/62380743#62380743).